# Accessing Multiple Redis Shards

Tags: redis

Hi I'm going to be using multiple Redis instances and some sharding between instances.

My question is will performance suffer [a noticeable amount] if loading a webpage requires multiple shards accessed.

My basic overview is to have load balanced between multiple Redis shards**footnote below*, possibly using Twemproxy for this.  And have everything pertaining to a particular users' data on only one shard, (for things like 'likes','user-information','save-list' etc.) but also have multiple instances of Redis containing objects (which many different users will access) and data about said objects which will load for users also.  I will not need to have Redis operations on multiple keys in different databases, but I will need to have Redis instances return m keys from n instances in real time.

To come completely clean with you I'm also planning on using something like this https://github.com/mpalmer/redis/blob/nds-2.6/README.nds so that I can use Redis while saving many keys to disc when not in use.

FOOTNOTE: (I am aware of Redis's Master-Slave replication, but prefer sharding for the extra storage in place of just more access)

*Please, if your only comment is along the lines of, ""don't bother to shard until you absolutely have to"", keep it to yourself.  I'm not interested in hearing responses that sharding is only important for a certain percentage of sites.  That may be your opinion and that may even be fact but that is not what I am asking here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, if you're going to perform multiple reads from multiple shards instead of a single instance, you're most likely to get better performance as long as:
1. The sharding layer isn't slowing you down
2. The app can pull the data from the different shards asynchronously

Comment: does select calls to different shards make a lag in performance